# Why does my steam game not verify it's download all the way?

Tags: steam

I try to download game on steam, and it doesn't verify the download. It gets to a point where the "Verifying download" stage ends, but it just goes back to 99% of the game downloaded. I tried to switch my dowload region, clear my cache files and retry the download all together. Still no change.

Does anyone know a solution to the problem? All of the help would be appreciated.

Comment: What game it is?

Comment: It's a MOBA called Smite. Had it before, but never had problems with it.

Comment: Have you uninstalled and reinstalled? With a third-party launcher and etc it may have something corrupted that's causing an issue.